# How to open a specific tab in a page using a link in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, tabs

i have a tab section in my webpage like below:

```html
<div class="portfolio-nav portfolio-page-nav mb-40">
  <ul>
    <li data-filter=".all" class="active">all works</li>
    <li data-filter=".photography" >photography</li>
    <li data-filter=".logos" >Graphic Design</li>
    <li data-filter=".socialmedia" >Social Media</li>
    <li data-filter=".interiordesign" >Interior Design</li>
    <li data-filter=".websites" >websites</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is my live url: [enter link description here](https://thebrandchimp.com/portfolio.php)
i want to send users a links where it will take them to this page and open a specific tab, can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Comment: Get even click on your li then use Window open() : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @SKJ i guess you didnt understand my question, i want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469890/how-do-i-get-a-link-to-open-a-specific-tab-on-a-page but as i dont have any anchor tag or href in my tab button, i cannot use that

Comment: You can use your data-filter

Comment: @SKJ, how? can you please show as an answer

Comment: @SKJ can u show me a reference or something or atleast share a link

Comment: You will find something if you type : get data click jquery

Comment: I have scanned the page code side and it's all messed up.  To get what you need the page to do, first, update the page totally and add all the necessary files. Then embark on what you want.

Comment: Look at this, maybe it's the best solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913641/link-from-another-page-element-to-a-specific-data-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913641/link-from-another-page-element-to-a-specific-data-filter)